# Google OAuth2.0 refresh access_token

Tags: oauth-2.0, access-token, google-signin, refresh-token

I'm making a function to post to google my business automatically by using Google my business API by javascript and firebase. The access token is obtained by authentication using Google Sign In.
However, the access token has an expiration date, so I have to renew it using a refresh token.
Can I use the "user.refreshToken" shown in the image below as the refresh token to be used in this case?
Thanks in advance.[Data retrieved upon sign-in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FhAYC.png)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are right. In general, the refresh token in an OAuth2.0 flow can be used to retrieve a new access token, which can then be used again to access resources. The refresh token normally has a much longer expiration date than the access token hence you can implement functionality like "remember me" using the refresh token.